# Is the Python "in" statement a loop?

Tags: python

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if 4 in numbers:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

When the "in" statement is executed, does this perform a loop through the numbers list to return a Boolean?

Comment: It does. But it depends on which data you `in` against, it's a bit different for strings, custom classes

Comment: FYI that's the `in` _operator_ in a [comparison _expression_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in an [`if` _statement_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```py
element in container
```

ends up executing `container.__contains__(element)`. So it's up the the container's type how to implement the special `__contains__` method.

For the list type, yes, the implementation does use a loop over the list elements. But other container types implement `__contains__` in other ways (for example, the set type uses a kind of hash table lookup).

Comment: It's too bad lists don't know when they're sorted, or you could use a binary search.